# SSD stays inactive during startup/shutdown

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd, speed

This morning I upgraded my laptop replacing the old 5400 rpm hdd with a new SSD (Kingston v300 480gb). Performance look good, both on benchmarks (crystal disk mark) than on personal feel. I'm encountering an issue though: startup and shutdown take veeeery long time, I think even more than the old HDD. I noticed that both during startup and shutdown, the ssd status led is lit for 3-4 seconds, than stays off for 1-2 minutes, then turns on for other 2-3 seconds and then the task (startup or shutdown) terminates. Substantially, the ssd stays inactive for the majority of the time. What should I check in a case like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was this a fresh install or did you clone the disk? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I cloned my old HDD running windows 8.1

Comment: Use the [Windows Performance Analyzer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158252-trace-why-windows-8-boots-shutsdown-or-hibernates-slowly/) to find out where it is getting stuck...

Comment: Try a fresh install of windows. It could be hung up on waiting for the HDD to execute an action that the SSD doesn't need to. A full restore or even just a sysprep may help.